# MySQL is deleting the last row of html table / Code Igniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

This is my controller, that i use to send the row to the model:

```
function excluir(){
    $codcliente = $this->input->post('codcliente');
    $this->load->model("Cliente_class");
    $this->Cliente_class->excluirCliente($codcliente);
    redirect('cliente/busca');
}
```

my model:

```
function excluirCliente($codcliente){
    $this->db->delete('cliente', array('codcliente' => $codcliente));
}
```

my table (view):

```
    <form action="#" method="POST" id="form">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <input type="button" onclick="cadastro();" value="Novo cliente" name="botao" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Código</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Cidade</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th> </th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($records as $row){ ?>
        <tr>
        <td><input name="codcliente" id="codcliente" value="<?php echo $row->codcliente ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->nome ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->cidade ?></td>
        <td><?php echo ($row->telefone == null) ? "-" : $row->telefone ?></td>
        <td><center><input type="button" onclick="excluir();" value="Delete"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </form>
    </thead>
    </table>
```

and my JS:

```
function excluir(){
document.forms['form'].action = "<?php base_url();?>excluir";
document.forms['form'].submit();
```

}

its working fine, but the code is deleting my last row in relation with the table on html. i used the order by too see whats beeing deleted, and it works the same...

i dont know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the same form name `name="codcliente"` for all your rows and then submitting the whole form when you delete. The server sees the last value for `codcliente` which will be your last row and hence deletes it.

To fix, I suggest you use unique form names for each row for all your row fields. Eg. Instead of `name="codcliente"` use `name="codcliente_<?php echo $row->id ?>`". And then when you post to the server to delete, use a `data-name=<?php echo $row->codcliente ?>` on the delete button and in the onClick handler use $(this).data('name') to get the unique name of the field and post that to the server. I suggest you use ids instead of names as well.

Comment: @Fiorucci Please check this, I also think this is the issue. phreakv6 is correct.

Comment: Hmm, it looks beeter than my code, ill do this here too see

Comment: its getting nothing, i dont know what i did here

Comment: ok, i did! i solved the problem with the name, now its getting the right value, thaaaaaaanks!